# Calculate the value of inputs and set the result in another field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a value `1000` and two input fields like `X` and `Y`.
If I put a value `300` on `X` then the value calculate with `1000` and automatically fill the `Y` field with `700`. Same as if I put the `Y` field first then `X` value will calculate automatically. The value can be anything below `1000`. If it's over `1000` then I want to show a alert message.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Please share your code you tried here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code we create 2 inputs and we listen for a change event on both.
When one input value changes, we set the other's value to 1000 - value.

```
<p>
First
<input min="0" max="1000" type="number" id="first">
</p>
<p>
  Second
<input  min="0" max="1000"  type="number"  id="second">
</p>
```

Js (with jquery):

```
$("#first").change((el)=>{
   $("#second").val(1000 - el.target.value);
});
$("#second").change((el)=>{
   $("#first").val(1000 - el.target.value);
});
```

https://codepen.io/Pocciox/pen/ExxzVXz

Comment: @sadaf No problem, next time you ask something i would advise including a CodePen with what you've already tried. This will make it more likely for people to play around with your code and answer your question.